# Xcode Cloud Build Number vs Target Build Number

Tags: xcode, shell, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

Is it best practice to keep the target build number (ie `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`) the same as Xcode Cloud's build number (ie `CI_BUILD_NUMBER`)?

If so, is there any way to be able to do that in an automated way? Would it happen inside 1 of the 3 Xcode Cloud shell scripts? Most of the scripts I find rely on `xcodebuild`, which I'm unable to get to work inside a script like `ci_post_clone.sh` given it relies on local file-paths.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear a way to do this in appstore rest api